# Error in UpdateProgress

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using `UpdateProgress` to show the progress during `Postback`, getting run time error that "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.get_element().style' is null or not an object"

**THIS IS MY SCRIPT:**

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    //Shows the modal popup - the update progress
    var popup = $find('<%= mdlProgress.ClientID %>');
    if (popup != null) {
        popup.show();
    }
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    //Hide the modal popup - the update progress
    var popup = $find('<%= mdlProgress.ClientID %>');
    if (popup != null) {
        popup.hide();
    }
}
```

**DESIGN CODE:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlProgress" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress"
                            PopupControlID="UpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
         <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server">
              <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/RIBO/Images/Processing.gif"    AlternateText="Processing"  runat="server" />
                </ProgressTemplate>
          </asp:UpdateProgress>
           </td>
         </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this.get_element is probably returning null. You can check by alert()ing the result of your $find method.

Have you considered using JQuery? It's perfect for this kind of thing.